# Read a specific field from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a select box that accepts multiple values. How can I read only the ID of the respective object from this array?

[image]

Comment: Share reproducible description, also what did you try till now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```js
values.forEach(value=>{
 console.log(value.id); //here you can access id of each object.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `id` of the objects as the `value` for the options and then you can extract the values wherever required like on form submission or selection change.

Refer to the snippet below:

```js
const options = [
  { label: "Apple", id: 1 },
  { label: "Mango", id: 2 },
  { label: "Banana", id: 3 },
  { label: "Kiwi", id: 4 },
  { label: "Watermelon", id: 5 },
];

function App() {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const currSelectedOptions = Array.from(target.selectedOptions).map(
      (opt) => opt.value
    );
    setSelectedOptions(currSelectedOptions);

    console.log("Selected Options", currSelectedOptions);
  };

  return (
    <select multiple value={selectedOptions} onChange={handleChange}>
      {options.map(({ label, id }) => (
        <option value={id} key={id}>
          {label}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```